# Blank page appears before title page

Tags: titles, setspace

I am writing my thesis paper in `LaTeX`. I wrote the title page like below. But whenever I compile the `.tex` file one extra blank page is added before the title page. I can't figure out why is it happening. Any help?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[12pt, twoside, makeidx,a4paper]{report}

\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx,paralist,verbatim,psfrag}
\usepackage {amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\restylefloat{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,}



\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
%\parskip=5pt

\def\squareforqed{\hbox{${\cal Q.E.D.}$}}               %modified
\def\qed{\ifmmode\squareforqed\else{\unskip\nobreak\hfil
\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak\hfil\squareforqed
\parfillskip=0pt\finalhyphendemerits=0\endgraf}\fi
\vskip 10pt}


%\topmargin=-.5cm
%\leftmargin=0true cm
%\oddsidemargin=-.5true cm
%\evensidemargin=-.5true cm

\topmargin=-.5cm \leftmargin=.5true cm \oddsidemargin=0true cm
\evensidemargin=0true cm

\textwidth=17cm
\textheight=23cm


\newcounter{linenumber}
\newenvironment{listprog}{%
        \begin{list}{%
                \footnotesize\arabic{linenumber}}{%
                   \usecounter{linenumber}%
%                   \setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}
                   \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
                   \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}}%
        {\end{list}}


\newcommand{\namelistlabel}[1]{\mbox{#1}\hfil}
\newenvironment{listing}[1]{%
        \begin{list}{*}{%
                \let\makelabel\namelistlabel
                 \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}%
                 \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.1\labelwidth}%
                 \advance \leftmargin by 18pt
                  \setlength{\labelsep}{5pt}%
                   \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
%                   \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
                   \setlength{\topsep}{5pt}%
%                   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}%
}{%
\end{list}}


\newcommand{\bta}{\hspace{7pt}}
\newcommand{\btb}{\hspace{14pt}}
\newcommand{\btc}{\hspace{21pt}}
\newcommand{\btd}{\hspace{28pt}}
\newcommand{\bte}{\hspace{35pt}}
\newcommand{\btf}{\hspace{42pt}}
\newcommand{\btg}{\hspace{49pt}}
\newcommand{\bth}{\hspace{56pt}}
\newcommand{\bti}{\hspace{63pt}}
\newcommand{\btj}{\hspace{70pt}}
\newcommand{\btk}{\hspace{77pt}}
\newcommand{\btl}{\hspace{84pt}}
\newcommand{\btm}{\hspace{91pt}}
\newcommand{\btn}{\hspace{98pt}}
\newcommand{\bto}{\hspace{150pt}}
\newcommand{\btp}{\hspace{160pt}}
\newcommand{\btq}{\hspace{170pt}}
\newcommand{\btr}{\hspace{180pt}}
\newcommand{\bts}{\hspace{190pt}}
\newcommand{\btt}{\hspace{200pt}}
\newcommand{\btu}{\hspace{210pt}}
\newcommand{\btv}{\hspace{220pt}}
\newcommand{\btw}{\hspace{230pt}}
\newcommand{\btx}{\hspace{240pt}}
\newcommand{\bty}{\hspace{250pt}}
\newcommand{\btz}{\hspace{260pt}}


\newcommand{\Begin} {{\bf begin}}
\newcommand{\End}   {{\bf end}}
\newcommand{\If}    {{\bf if }}
\newcommand{\Then}  {{\bf then }}
\newcommand{\Else}  {{\bf else }}
\newcommand{\For}   {{\bf for }}
\newcommand{\To}    {{\bf to }}
\newcommand{\DownTo}    {{\bf downto }}
\newcommand{\Do}    {{\bf do }}
\newcommand{\While} {{\bf while }}
\newcommand{\Repeat}{{\bf repeat }}
\newcommand{\Until} {{\bf until}}
\newcommand{\Procedure} {{\bf Procedure }}
\newcommand{\Function} {{\bf Function }}
\newcommand{\Return} {{\bf return }}
\newcommand{\Integer} {{\bf integer}}
\newcommand{\Boolean} {{\bf Boolean}}


\newcommand{\boxbox}{\rule{3mm}{3mm}}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand{\setcount}[2]{\setcounter{#1}{\arabic{#2}}}
\newcommand{\num}[2]{\setcounter{tmp}{\arabic{#1}}\addtocounter{tmp}{#2}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{tmp}}}
\newcommand{\fdeg}{$f$-degree }
\newcommand{\bound}[1]{$#1$-bounded}
\newcommand{\dBound}[1]{$(d_f,#1)$-partition}
\newcommand{\DBound}[1]{$(\Delta,#1)$-partition}
\newcommand{\class}{${\cal C}$}
\newcommand{\Delt}{\Delta_{f}}
\newcommand{\chr}{\chi^\prime}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{\noindent{\em Case} #1: }
\newcommand{\Case}[1]{\noindent{\em Case} #1: }
\newcommand{\minvp}{\min\{\#\varphi,\#\psi\}}


\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[lemma]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{fact}[lemma]{Fact}
\newcommand{\proof}{\noindent {\bf Proof.} \ \ }
%\newcommand{\proofend}{\begin{flushright${\cal Q.E.D.}$\end{flushright}}
%\newcommand{\proofend}{
%       {\hfill{${\cal Q.E.D.}$}}
%
%                   \ }
\newcommand{\dvgraph}{divided vertex graph}
\newcommand{\wrt}{with respect to }


\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\D}{{\cal D}}
\newcommand{\E}{{\cal E}}
\newcommand{\F}{{\cal F}}
\newcommand{\G}{{\cal G}}
\renewcommand{\H}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\I}{{\cal I}}
\renewcommand{\L}{{\cal L}}
\newcommand{\LC}{L^*}
\newcommand{\aaa}{{\"a}}
\newcommand{\pp}{{\prime\prime}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{{\prime\prime\prime}}
\newcommand{\Eq}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\lsup}{\beta_{\rm sup}}

\newcommand{\color}[1]{\lceil (#1+2)^2/2\rceil}
\newcommand{\gcolor}{\lceil 72(g(G)+2)^2/5\rceil}

\newcommand{\newsubset}{$\subseteq$\hspace{-7pt}{$_{_/}$}}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % without this line the Refenrence will be replaced by bibliography

\makeindex
\makeglossary



\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\def\baselinestretch{1.1}
\title{{\large B.Sc. Engg. Thesis}\\
\vspace{2cm} 
\textbf{On Cover Contact Graphs}}
\author{ By \\
 Md. Taufique Hussain \\
 Student No. 0805050 \\
 Shohedul Hasan \\
 Student No. 0805060\\
 \vspace{2cm}
 \\
{ Submitted to}\\
 {Department of Computer Science and Engineering} \\
  { in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the
degree of}\\
\vspace{3cm}
{ Bachelor of Science in Computer Science and Engineering}\\
%\vspace{3cm}
%{(Preliminary version)}\\
{ Department of Computer Science and Engineering}\\
{ Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology (BUET)}\\
\vspace{1cm}
{ Dhaka-1000}
        }

\date{June 13, 2014}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%\input board.tex \newpage

%\input declaration.tex \newpage




\def\baselinestretch{1.55}

\normalsize{

\tableofcontents \newpage
\listoffigures \newpage
\listoftables 
\newpage
}





\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
\normalsize{
%\input Acknowledgement.tex \newpage

%\input Abstract.tex \newpage
}


\def\baselinestretch{1.8}


%\input Chap_1.tex %introduction
%\input Chap_2.tex %preliminery
%\input Chap_3.tex %CCG of convex point sets
%\input chap4.tex %CCG of non-convex point sets
%\input Chap_5.tex %Conclusion
%\input chap6.tex
%\input publication.tex
%\input references.tex




%
%\input conclusion.tex
%

%\bibliography{Book,PhDThesis,Journal,Proceeding,Report,Manuscript,Zhou,Zhou.world}
%
%\newpage
%  \printmypapers
%
%
%
\newpage
\printindex
%
%\newpage
%\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to put `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after `\maketitle`. Wild guess in the absence of complete mwe.

Comment: Still same. Should I give full code?

Comment: Yes, you should edit your question to provide a complete document that's just big enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @taufique, yes, unless we can (attempt) to compile it in the same manner as you do, then how are we going to be able to help.

Comment: @taufique: I suggest an edit of the question title, because it is not connected to corollaries obviously.

Comment: Christian Hupfer, Sorry I previously wanted to ask a question related to writing corollaries which was later resolved.
daleif, I thought posting whole code is not appropriate way to sak question.

Comment: @taufique: Your MWE does not compile and it is by far not minimal `;-)`

Comment: I have commented out dependent files. Now it should compile.

Comment: @taufique: Do you really need this grotesque `\baselinestretch` redefinitions, which are strongly discouraged nowadays? I checked just now: They seem to enlarge your titlepage such that it does not fit on the first page and is shipped out the next one!

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I am writing on a template. I still don't know LaTeX very good. So I didn't change the template as long as it's working.

Comment: @taufique: This 'template' looks like if twenty people have piled on commands over a period of ten years and publish it to others `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution, with `setspace` and `geometry` packages.

A wild *jumping* from one `\baselinestretch` to another one is confusing, as well as the redefinition of that length is strongly discouraged. The titlepage was too large, therefore shipped out on the 2nd page, leaving the 1st one empty.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[tmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}%


\usepackage{setspace}%
%\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx,paralist,verbatim,psfrag}
\usepackage {amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\restylefloat{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\title{{\large B.Sc. Engg. Thesis}\\
\vspace{2cm} 
\textbf{On Cover Contact Graphs}}
\author{ By \\
 Md. Taufique Hussain \\
 Student No. 0805050 \\
 Shohedul Hasan \\
 Student No. 0805060\\
 \vspace{2cm}
 \\
{ Submitted to}\\
 {Department of Computer Science and Engineering} \\
  { in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the
degree of}\\
\vspace{3cm}
{ Bachelor of Science in Computer Science and Engineering}\\
%\vspace{3cm}
%{(Preliminary version)}\\
{ Department of Computer Science and Engineering}\\
{ Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology (BUET)}\\
\vspace{1cm}
{ Dhaka-1000}
        }
\date{June 13, 2014}
%

%\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,}




\def\squareforqed{\hbox{${\cal Q.E.D.}$}}               %modified
\def\qed{\ifmmode\squareforqed\else{\unskip\nobreak\hfil
\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak\hfil\squareforqed
\parfillskip=0pt\finalhyphendemerits=0\endgraf}\fi
\vskip 10pt}


%\topmargin=-.5cm
%\leftmargin=0true cm
%\oddsidemargin=-.5true cm
%\evensidemargin=-.5true cm


%\topmargin=-.5cm \leftmargin=.5true cm \oddsidemargin=0true cm
%\evensidemargin=0true cm

%\textwidth=17cm
%\textheight=23cm


\newcounter{linenumber}
\newenvironment{listprog}{%
        \begin{list}{%
                \footnotesize\arabic{linenumber}}{%
                   \usecounter{linenumber}%
%                   \setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}
                   \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
                   \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}}%
        {\end{list}}


\newcommand{\namelistlabel}[1]{\mbox{#1}\hfil}
\newenvironment{listing}[1]{%
        \begin{list}{*}{%
                \let\makelabel\namelistlabel
                 \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}%
                 \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.1\labelwidth}%
                 \advance \leftmargin by 18pt
                  \setlength{\labelsep}{5pt}%
                   \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
%                   \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
                   \setlength{\topsep}{5pt}%
%                   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}%
}{%
\end{list}}


\newcommand{\bta}{\hspace{7pt}}
\newcommand{\btb}{\hspace{14pt}}
\newcommand{\btc}{\hspace{21pt}}
\newcommand{\btd}{\hspace{28pt}}
\newcommand{\bte}{\hspace{35pt}}
\newcommand{\btf}{\hspace{42pt}}
\newcommand{\btg}{\hspace{49pt}}
\newcommand{\bth}{\hspace{56pt}}
\newcommand{\bti}{\hspace{63pt}}
\newcommand{\btj}{\hspace{70pt}}
\newcommand{\btk}{\hspace{77pt}}
\newcommand{\btl}{\hspace{84pt}}
\newcommand{\btm}{\hspace{91pt}}
\newcommand{\btn}{\hspace{98pt}}
\newcommand{\bto}{\hspace{150pt}}
\newcommand{\btp}{\hspace{160pt}}
\newcommand{\btq}{\hspace{170pt}}
\newcommand{\btr}{\hspace{180pt}}
\newcommand{\bts}{\hspace{190pt}}
\newcommand{\btt}{\hspace{200pt}}
\newcommand{\btu}{\hspace{210pt}}
\newcommand{\btv}{\hspace{220pt}}
\newcommand{\btw}{\hspace{230pt}}
\newcommand{\btx}{\hspace{240pt}}
\newcommand{\bty}{\hspace{250pt}}
\newcommand{\btz}{\hspace{260pt}}


\newcommand{\Begin} {{\bf begin}}
\newcommand{\End}   {{\bf end}}
\newcommand{\If}    {{\bf if }}
\newcommand{\Then}  {{\bf then }}
\newcommand{\Else}  {{\bf else }}
\newcommand{\For}   {{\bf for }}
\newcommand{\To}    {{\bf to }}
\newcommand{\DownTo}    {{\bf downto }}
\newcommand{\Do}    {{\bf do }}
\newcommand{\While} {{\bf while }}
\newcommand{\Repeat}{{\bf repeat }}
\newcommand{\Until} {{\bf until}}
\newcommand{\Procedure} {{\bf Procedure }}
\newcommand{\Function} {{\bf Function }}
\newcommand{\Return} {{\bf return }}
\newcommand{\Integer} {{\bf integer}}
\newcommand{\Boolean} {{\bf Boolean}}


\newcommand{\boxbox}{\rule{3mm}{3mm}}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand{\setcount}[2]{\setcounter{#1}{\arabic{#2}}}
\newcommand{\num}[2]{\setcounter{tmp}{\arabic{#1}}\addtocounter{tmp}{#2}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{tmp}}}
\newcommand{\fdeg}{$f$-degree }
\newcommand{\bound}[1]{$#1$-bounded}
\newcommand{\dBound}[1]{$(d_f,#1)$-partition}
\newcommand{\DBound}[1]{$(\Delta,#1)$-partition}
\newcommand{\class}{${\cal C}$}
\newcommand{\Delt}{\Delta_{f}}
\newcommand{\chr}{\chi^\prime}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{\noindent{\em Case} #1: }
\newcommand{\Case}[1]{\noindent{\em Case} #1: }
\newcommand{\minvp}{\min\{\#\varphi,\#\psi\}}


\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[lemma]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{fact}[lemma]{Fact}
\newcommand{\proof}{\noindent {\bf Proof.} \ \ }
%\newcommand{\proofend}{\begin{flushright${\cal Q.E.D.}$\end{flushright}}
%\newcommand{\proofend}{
%       {\hfill{${\cal Q.E.D.}$}}
%
%                   \ }
\newcommand{\dvgraph}{divided vertex graph}
\newcommand{\wrt}{with respect to }


\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\D}{{\cal D}}
\newcommand{\E}{{\cal E}}
\newcommand{\F}{{\cal F}}
\newcommand{\G}{{\cal G}}
\renewcommand{\H}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\I}{{\cal I}}
\renewcommand{\L}{{\cal L}}
\newcommand{\LC}{L^*}
\newcommand{\aaa}{{\"a}}
\newcommand{\pp}{{\prime\prime}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{{\prime\prime\prime}}
\newcommand{\Eq}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\lsup}{\beta_{\rm sup}}

\newcommand{\color}[1]{\lceil (#1+2)^2/2\rceil}
\newcommand{\gcolor}{\lceil 72(g(G)+2)^2/5\rceil}

\newcommand{\newsubset}{$\subseteq$\hspace{-7pt}{$_{_/}$}}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % without this line the Refenrence will be replaced by bibliography

\makeindex
\makeglossary



\begin{document}
\linespread{1.1}%
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\linespread{1.0}

\normalsize{

\tableofcontents \newpage
\listoffigures \newpage
\listoftables 
\newpage
}



\chapter{First}



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Repost of the basically unchanged original OP post**

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, makeidx,a4paper]{report}

\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} % Was commented out in original post version
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx,paralist,verbatim,psfrag}
\usepackage {amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\restylefloat{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,}



\parskip=5pt

\def\squareforqed{\hbox{${\cal Q.E.D.}$}}               %modified
\def\qed{\ifmmode\squareforqed\else{\unskip\nobreak\hfil
\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak\hfil\squareforqed
\parfillskip=0pt\finalhyphendemerits=0\endgraf}\fi
\vskip 10pt}


%\topmargin=-.5cm
%\leftmargin=0true cm
%\oddsidemargin=-.5true cm
%\evensidemargin=-.5true cm

\topmargin=-.5cm \leftmargin=.5true cm \oddsidemargin=0true cm
\evensidemargin=0true cm

\textwidth=17cm
\textheight=23cm


\newcounter{linenumber}
\newenvironment{listprog}{%
        \begin{list}{%
                \footnotesize\arabic{linenumber}}{%
                   \usecounter{linenumber}%
%                   \setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}
                   \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
                   \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}}%
        {\end{list}}


\newcommand{\namelistlabel}[1]{\mbox{#1}\hfil}
\newenvironment{listing}[1]{%
        \begin{list}{*}{%
                \let\makelabel\namelistlabel
                 \settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}%
                 \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.1\labelwidth}%
                 \advance \leftmargin by 18pt
                  \setlength{\labelsep}{5pt}%
                   \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
%                   \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
                   \setlength{\topsep}{5pt}%
%                   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}%
}{%
\end{list}}


\newcommand{\bta}{\hspace{7pt}}
\newcommand{\btb}{\hspace{14pt}}
\newcommand{\btc}{\hspace{21pt}}
\newcommand{\btd}{\hspace{28pt}}
\newcommand{\bte}{\hspace{35pt}}
\newcommand{\btf}{\hspace{42pt}}
\newcommand{\btg}{\hspace{49pt}}
\newcommand{\bth}{\hspace{56pt}}
\newcommand{\bti}{\hspace{63pt}}
\newcommand{\btj}{\hspace{70pt}}
\newcommand{\btk}{\hspace{77pt}}
\newcommand{\btl}{\hspace{84pt}}
\newcommand{\btm}{\hspace{91pt}}
\newcommand{\btn}{\hspace{98pt}}
\newcommand{\bto}{\hspace{150pt}}
\newcommand{\btp}{\hspace{160pt}}
\newcommand{\btq}{\hspace{170pt}}
\newcommand{\btr}{\hspace{180pt}}
\newcommand{\bts}{\hspace{190pt}}
\newcommand{\btt}{\hspace{200pt}}
\newcommand{\btu}{\hspace{210pt}}
\newcommand{\btv}{\hspace{220pt}}
\newcommand{\btw}{\hspace{230pt}}
\newcommand{\btx}{\hspace{240pt}}
\newcommand{\bty}{\hspace{250pt}}
\newcommand{\btz}{\hspace{260pt}}


\newcommand{\Begin} {{\bf begin}}
\newcommand{\End}   {{\bf end}}
\newcommand{\If}    {{\bf if }}
\newcommand{\Then}  {{\bf then }}
\newcommand{\Else}  {{\bf else }}
\newcommand{\For}   {{\bf for }}
\newcommand{\To}    {{\bf to }}
\newcommand{\DownTo}    {{\bf downto }}
\newcommand{\Do}    {{\bf do }}
\newcommand{\While} {{\bf while }}
\newcommand{\Repeat}{{\bf repeat }}
\newcommand{\Until} {{\bf until}}
\newcommand{\Procedure} {{\bf Procedure }}
\newcommand{\Function} {{\bf Function }}
\newcommand{\Return} {{\bf return }}
\newcommand{\Integer} {{\bf integer}}
\newcommand{\Boolean} {{\bf Boolean}}


\newcommand{\boxbox}{\rule{3mm}{3mm}}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand{\setcount}[2]{\setcounter{#1}{\arabic{#2}}}
\newcommand{\num}[2]{\setcounter{tmp}{\arabic{#1}}\addtocounter{tmp}{#2}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{tmp}}}
\newcommand{\fdeg}{$f$-degree }
\newcommand{\bound}[1]{$#1$-bounded}
\newcommand{\dBound}[1]{$(d_f,#1)$-partition}
\newcommand{\DBound}[1]{$(\Delta,#1)$-partition}
\newcommand{\class}{${\cal C}$}
\newcommand{\Delt}{\Delta_{f}}
\newcommand{\chr}{\chi^\prime}
\newcommand{\case}[1]{\noindent{\em Case} #1: }
\newcommand{\Case}[1]{\noindent{\em Case} #1: }
\newcommand{\minvp}{\min\{\#\varphi,\#\psi\}}


\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[lemma]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{fact}[lemma]{Fact}
\newcommand{\proof}{\noindent {\bf Proof.} \ \ }
%\newcommand{\proofend}{\begin{flushright${\cal Q.E.D.}$\end{flushright}}
%\newcommand{\proofend}{
%       {\hfill{${\cal Q.E.D.}$}}
%
%                   \ }
\newcommand{\dvgraph}{divided vertex graph}
\newcommand{\wrt}{with respect to }


\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\D}{{\cal D}}
\newcommand{\E}{{\cal E}}
\newcommand{\F}{{\cal F}}
\newcommand{\G}{{\cal G}}
\renewcommand{\H}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\I}{{\cal I}}
\renewcommand{\L}{{\cal L}}
\newcommand{\LC}{L^*}
\newcommand{\aaa}{{\"a}}
\newcommand{\pp}{{\prime\prime}}
\newcommand{\ppp}{{\prime\prime\prime}}
\newcommand{\Eq}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\lsup}{\beta_{\rm sup}}

\newcommand{\color}[1]{\lceil (#1+2)^2/2\rceil}
\newcommand{\gcolor}{\lceil 72(g(G)+2)^2/5\rceil}

\newcommand{\newsubset}{$\subseteq$\hspace{-7pt}{$_{_/}$}}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} % without this line the Refenrence will be replaced by bibliography

\makeindex
\makeglossary



\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\def\baselinestretch{1.1}
\title{{\large B.Sc. Engg. Thesis}\\
\vspace{2cm} 
\textbf{On Cover Contact Graphs}}
\author{ By \\
 Md. Taufique Hussain \\
 Student No. 0805050 \\
 Shohedul Hasan \\
 Student No. 0805060\\
 \vspace{2cm}
 \\
{ Submitted to}\\
 {Department of Computer Science and Engineering} \\
  { in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the
degree of}\\
\vspace{3cm}
{ Bachelor of Science in Computer Science and Engineering}\\
%\vspace{3cm}
%{(Preliminary version)}\\
{ Department of Computer Science and Engineering}\\
{ Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology (BUET)}\\
\vspace{1cm}
{ Dhaka-1000}
        }

\date{June 13, 2014}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%\input board.tex \newpage

%\input declaration.tex \newpage





\normalsize{

\tableofcontents \newpage
\listoffigures \newpage
\listoftables 
\newpage
}





%\def\baselinestretch{1.6}
\normalsize{
%\input%\input Acknowledgement.tex \newpage

%\input%\input Abstract.tex \newpage
}


%\def\baselinestretch{1.8}


%\input%\input Chap_1.tex %introduction
%\input%\input Chap_2.tex %preliminery
%\input%\input Chap_3.tex %CCG of convex point sets
%\input chap4.tex %CCG of non-convex point sets
%\input%\input Chap_5.tex %Conclusion
%\input chap6.tex
%\input publication.tex
%\input references.tex




%
%\input conclusion.tex
%

%\bibliography{Book,PhDThesis,Journal,Proceeding,Report,Manuscript,Zhou,Zhou.world}
%
%\newpage
%  \printmypapers
%
%
%
\newpage
\printindex
%
%\newpage
%\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: It was ok before I added any chapter. But when I am adding chapter it's not compiling, even when chapter contains nothing but this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7638947/

Comment: @taufique: I accidentally commented `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` out. I changed that a few seconds ago

Comment: Same file that was previously compiled is not being compiled now. Error report says: 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.231 \chapter{Chap_4.tex}

What to do now?

Comment: @taufique, `\chapter` is a command for typesetting a chapter heading, not including a file, as I presume you mean to do. Use `\input{<filename>}` or `\include{<filename>}` instead.

Comment: @taufique: I stepped back and just commented out your `\input` statements and those `weird` `\baselinestretch` commands, the output is the same as from my code. It runs without errors.

Comment: @PaulGessler: I assumed already that `\chapter` was the error, thanks!

Comment: I could resolve it. I primarily didn't notice it. Document looks nicer now. :-D Now would you please explain what was wrong in previous code and what did you change? So that I can learn.

Comment: @taufique: You did a lot of `\baselinestretch` redefinitions, enlarging the space between to text lines by multiplying (*stretching*) the normal space of `\baselineskip`. By setting it to `1.6` or even `1.8` you effectively multiply the space by 1.6 or nearly 2, which gets even worse since the stretching is connected to chosen font size.

Comment: What should I do if I want to increase spacing between two lines?

Comment: @taufique: Use `\linespread{1.05}` or any other moderate factor. Afterwards, use `\linespread{1.0}` to restore the default setting

Answer (score 7):

Your title page is too big, that's why it produces a second page. Please reduce the height of your title page by adapting the vspaces.

You should try to avoid that many manual treatment of baseline stretching and vertical spaces. I haven't seen your thesis yet, but this will unlikely look that good. Just an advice.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, twoside, makeidx, a4paper]{report}
\title{{\large B.Sc.\ Engg.\ Thesis}\\
\vspace{2cm} 
\textbf{On Cover Contact Graphs}}
\author{By \\
 Md. XY XY \\
 Student No.\ 0000000 \\
 XY XY \\
 Student No.\ 0000000\\
 \vspace{1cm}
 \\
Submitted to\\
Department of Computer Science and Engineering\\
in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the
degree of\\
\vspace{1cm}
Bachelor of Science in Computer Science and Engineering\\
Department of Computer Science and Engineering\\
Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology (BUET)\\
\vspace{1cm}
Dhaka-1000}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{input1}
\end{document}
```

[image]